# TestFlight claims new version of iOS app can't support macOS 11 on Apple Silicon, only 12. Why?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, mac-catalyst, mac-app-store

I'm updating one of my iOS apps, which I also have set to allow distribution on the Mac app store, for Apple Silicon.

My app has a deployment target of iOs 9.0, so its quite backwards compatible. Yet, TestFlight gives me this warning:

> The app is not compatible with the provided minimum macOS version of 11.0. It can run on macOS 12.0 or later. Please specify an LSMinimumSystemVersion value of 12.0 or later in a new build, or select a compatible version in App Store Connect.

what could it possibly see in my app that makes it think it can't support macOS 11, if (which is the equivalent of a deployment target of 14.x) and requires 12.0?

Any ideas, anyone?

Comment: Searching indicates that you should supply an explicit `LSMinimumSystemVersion` in your info.plist rather than relying on default. Maybe try that with 11.0?

Comment: FWIW tried <key>LSMinimumSystemVersion</key><string>11</string> as well as 11.0, to no avail.